# Are there any watermark apps for android?

Tags: android, watermark, apple, apps

Since we have now few cameras with Built-in WiFi, like Canon 6D and 70D,
we are more dependent of using mobile phones, for editing, sharing and so on.
But watermark is a very importante thing, especially if you want to share your work.
So I was wondering if someone here use an app (I particulary use android, but I have lot's of friends that has IOS, so both of them will be useful) that do such a thing.

---

ps: I've made a research and I didn't find any question like that.

Comment: I'd suggest that I wouldn't want to watermark anything as being from me without first post-producing it on something with a screen bigger than a camera or a smartphone.  Also, are you referring to digital watermarking or adding a logo of some kind to the corner of the image.

Comment: Good suggestion, @AJHenderson. I mean adding a logo to the corner. I work shooting shows and I usually do this, but I lose some time to download the images to a laptop and post it. Since it's just to upload to facebook and instagram It's not necessary a post-production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a Google search for ["how to watermark images android"](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20watermark%20images%20instagram&oq=how%20to%20watermark%20images%20instagram&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j0l3j69i62.5548j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#fp=52d1aa6c54e72276&q=how%20to%20watermark%20images%20android).

I found this which seems like what you want: [iWatermark](http://plumamazing.com/iphone/iwatermark-iphone/) for Android

> Secure and protect your photos. If you are a photographer or artist iWatermark works for you to by adding a visible personal text or graphic watermark.

You could also take a look at some more involved options:

- http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/23/image-processing-watermarking-on-the-fly/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744263/how-do-i-place-a-water-mark-image-on-image-that-i-just-took-a-picture-of-it-in-a

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @dpollitt. That's why I really like photo.stackexchange, to help each other. I didn't know about this app, I've tested the Add Watermark, but I didn't like. I downloaded the iWatermark and I liked, I'm gonna buy it.